# how t install arcgis using dbutils.library.installPyPI('arcgis', version='1.8.3', extras="all")?

Tags: cluster-computing, databricks, arcgis

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Process List(/local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-d884db6d-e16b-4db6-8a55-e427af51abe7/bin/python, /local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-d884db6d-e16b-4db6-8a55-e427af51abe7/bin/pip, install, arcgis[all]==1.8.3, --disable-pip-version-check) exited with code 1.     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Comment: I am getting above mentioned error when i am runnnig the command dbutils.library.installPyPI('arcgis')  Please help me.

Comment: Hey and welcome. You need to give us some context, e.g. share your code. Also some text (a question) not only copy an log-message will help!

Answer (score 0):

If you expand the error button, the error ultimately is `AttributeError: module 'site' has no attribute 'getsitepackages'`. This is something related to use of virtual environment of python, not particularly related to Databricks.
One old version of `arcgis` gets successfully installed however, `dbutils.library.installPyPI('arcgis', version='1.6.2')`.
You may try to fix this problem by editing the egg file of latest version of `arcgis` package, by comparing that with arcgis version 1.6.2.
`setup.py` of `arcgis` package has reference to `site.getsitepackages()` - this is not working within a virtual environment created using Python 3.7 as reported by many, follow [this link on github](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/737) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The above version of arcgis is working. I used                                   from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
print(get_python_lib())                                                      command                                      
 & its giving me path       /local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-1570f37a-f9f4-466d-9ff4-79e922e24de5/lib/python3.7/site-packages